# Is there a square with all corner points on the spiral $r=k\theta$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \infty$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ergodic-theory, euclidean-geometry, fixed-point-theorems, curves

I've posted this question on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203013/is-there-a-square-with-all-corner-points-on-the-spiral-r-k-theta-0-leq-the), but I want to bring it here too, because 1) the proof seems missing in the literature, although they are some sporadic mentions and 2) maybe it requires more sophisticated topological tools to prove it or disprove it, like bordism arguments that have been used before for some cases of the square peg problem, and these are out of my reach.

The question is:

> Is there a square that all of its corner points lie in the spiral
> $$r = k\theta \quad 0 \leq \theta \leq \infty $$
> ?

Comment: @TerryTao, do you see any way to adapt results on the Toeplitz square peg problem to answer this question, or to prove the existence of inscribed squares on other spirals?

Answer (score 12):

The points on the spiral with $\theta=$
$$
3.4535999354657\\
15.1248305526170\\
22.0370015553781\\
16.3950081067565
$$ form a square.

[image]

The numbers can be generated from this Mathematica code, if anyone wants to play with the algorithm and the initial conditions:

```
start = {{r, 15}, {s, 16}};    
curve[r_] := {r Cos[r], r Sin[r]};
rotate[{x_, y_}] := {-y, x};
left[p_, q_] := (p + q + rotate[q - p])/2;
right[p_, q_] := (p + q - rotate[q - p])/2;
curvedist[p_] := Norm[p - curve[Norm[p]]]^2;
test[p_, q_] := curvedist[left[p, q]] + curvedist[right[p, q]];
m = FindMinimum[test[curve[r], curve[s]], start];
{r, s, left[curve[r], curve[s]] // Norm, 
  right[curve[r], curve[s]] // Norm} /. m[[2]]
```

*Update:* Initial conditions with a Pythagorean form

```
start = {{r, Pi(m^2+2mn-n^2)p}, {s, Pi(-m^2+2mn+n^2)p}}
```

for positive integer $m,n,p$ with $m<n<m(1+\sqrt{2})$ always seem to produce squares on the spiral. The case $m=1$, $n=2$, $p=1$ leads to the solution above. Furthermore, the far point of each of these squares seems to be very close to the near point for another square! E.g. the first square ends at $\theta=22.03700...$ and the next square in that line begins with $\theta=22.03797...$

[image]

Comment: +1. My explanation: one vertex is placed on an arm; then side length and tilt are adjusted to make the 2 adjacent vertices both fall on an another arm, and finally the whole thing slides around (while being recalibrated) until the far vertex falls on an arm too. This scheme here correspond to a $1/2$ ratio in that the middle vertices are 2 arms away from the base and the far one is 1 arm away from them. Presumably one could carry out a similar scheme for every rational in $(\sqrt{2}-1,1)$. And presumably one could also try schemes where the 2 middle vertices don't lie on the same arm.

Comment: @Matt The pattern is beautiful! I've tried to look this up in classical geometrical theorems for the spiral, but without success. I'll play with the code too.

Comment: A more general set of good starting points is
$$r=\frac{\pi}{k}(2i^2−j^2k^2),\ s=\frac{\pi}{k}(2i^2+4ijk+j^2k^2)$$
where $i,j,k$ are positive integers and $i>jk/\sqrt{2}$; this produces all the squares above and also some squares which stay away from the $x$-axis.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, Sliding and adjusting sometimes slides to a degenerate solution, and sometimes slides to non-solutions -- so the part I found challenging was finding a good starting position. For squares with middle vertices on the same arm, the starting points above should be enough. For middle vertices on different arms, different starting points are needed, e.g.: for a square with vertices roughly $(3,7,9,11)2\pi$ away from the origin, the starting point of $r=6\pi, s=22\pi$ won't work, but a more complicated parameterization yields $r\simeq19, s\simeq70$ as a starting point, and that works.

Comment: By the last comment in the answer, it seems that the sequence of squares satisfy some ergodic behaviour similar to what we can find in irrational rotations. I will add the tag of ergodic theory to see if maybe this approach can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

For the non-negative reals $I= [0,\infty[$,
the Archimedean spiral is the image of the smooth injection
$$ \phi: I \to \mathbb{C},~~~ \alpha \mapsto \alpha \,e^{i\,\alpha}, $$
the inverse of which is the restriction of the complex absolute value
$$ |\,|:\mathbb{C} \to I,~~~z\mapsto|z|. $$
This implies that $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is on the spiral iff $\phi(|z|)~=~z$.
The linear bijection $R:~\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^2$
$$ 
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
z_1\\z_2
\end{array} } \right)
~\mapsto~
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\,
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
e^{i\,\pi/4} &e^{-i\,\pi/4}\\
e^{-i\,\pi/4}&e^{i\,\pi/4}
\end{array} } \right)\,
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
z_1\\z_2
\end{array} } \right)
$$
rotates a pair of diagonally opposite points $z_1,z_2$ of some square  by $\pi/2$ to the left into the other pair of corners of this square.

Assume that there is a square on $\phi(I)$. Then there exist a pair of reals $0\leq\alpha<\beta$  which map on   diagonally opposite corners such that with componentwise application one has
$$ 
\phi\left(\left|R \phi
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\\beta
\end{array} } \right)
\right| \right) ~=~
R \phi
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\\beta
\end{array} } \right).
$$
Calculation yields the reals that map into the other corners as
$$ 
\rho
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\\beta
\end{array} } \right)
~=~ \left|R \phi
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\\beta
\end{array} } \right)
\right|   ~=~
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\, 
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\sqrt{\alpha^2 +\beta^2 + 2\alpha\,\beta\,\sin(\beta-\alpha)}
\\
\sqrt{\alpha^2 +\beta^2 - 2\alpha\,\beta\,\sin(\beta-\alpha)}
\end{array} } \right)~=~
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
v_+\\v_-
\end{array} } \right)
\in I^2.
$$
If $\phi(v_+,v_-)$ are the other corner points of the square, one also has
$$
\rho^2
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\\beta
\end{array} } \right)
~=~
\rho \left( {\begin{array}{c}
v_+\\v_-
\end{array} } \right)
~=~
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\beta\\\alpha
\end{array} } \right).
$$
**Update:**

Because $v_+^2+v_-^2~=~\alpha^2+\beta^2$
this is equivalent to the conditions
$$
2\,\beta^2~=~\alpha^2+\beta^2+\sin(v_--v_+)\,v_+\, v_-,
$$
$$
2\,\alpha^2~=~\alpha^2+\beta^2-\sin(v_--v_+)\,v_+\, v_-,
$$
which imply
\begin{equation}
    \beta^2-\alpha^2~=~ 2\,\sin(v_--v_+)\,v_+\, v_-.
\end{equation}

Comment: @ Christian Remling: $\rho=|R\phi|$ maps the real radii of the first pair of corners to the real radii of the second pair by rotating the points in $\mathbb{C}^2$ around their center and then taking the absolute value, this operation works for all   $0\leq\alpha<\beta$. Only if the rotated points are also on the spiral the repeated application switches $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  I try to formulate the sentence more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So $\rho$ is your notation for the composite map $R\circ\phi$, followed by taking the absolute value. (It looked like a real constant to me.)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it took me some hours to check it completely. It's very clean, but I have a doubt. It seems that the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ from the $\rho
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\\beta
\end{array} } \right)$ calculation is not inherited correctly in the conditions. In the corrected form, it gives me $\beta^2~=\frac{1}{2}(~\alpha^2+\beta^2+\sin(v_--v_+)\,v_+\, v_-)$
and $
\alpha^2~=\frac{1}{2}(~\alpha^2+\beta^2-\sin(v_--v_+)\,v_+\, v_-)
$, which yields the trivial $0=0$ at the end. Let me know if the issue can be confirmed or refuted.

Comment: I guess you are right, I got this doubt, too, and it fits better with my earlier attempts. I clear it up when I find the time later. In this case you get only one set of conditions $f(\alpha,\beta)=0$ by subtracting the two equations and then have to do a third rotation and compare it to the first to get a second set of equations $g(\alpha,\beta)=0$.  One then may find solutions.

Comment: I updated the solution and hope it is correct now.

Comment: Combining the equations, we have $0=(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2})^{2}-4\alpha^{2}\beta^{2}\sin^{2}(\alpha-\beta)-((\beta^{2}-\alpha^{2})^2+4\alpha^{2}\beta^{2}\cos^{2}(\alpha-\beta))=0$. It makes sense because the condition for the diagonal is implicit in the rotation and it can't give an additional independent equation.

Comment: It gives me only one independent equation at the end and I missed the detail before. The crucial step is when obtaining the conditions from the $\rho
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
\alpha\\\beta
\end{array} } \right)$. By applying a rotation, we're calculating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|v_{-}+iv_{+}|$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|v_{-}+iv_{+}|$. We can expand one of them: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|v_{-}+iv_{+}|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{|v_{-}|^{2}+|v_{+}|^{2}+2|v_{-}||v_{+}|\sin(v_{-}-v_{+})}$. We forgot the 2 that is multiplying the last term (Corrected*)

Comment: So, the right-side of the conditions are $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}\pm 2v_{-}v_{+}\sin(v_{-}-v_{+}))$. This results in $\beta^2-\alpha^2~=~ 2\sin(v_--v_+)\,v_+\, v_-\;\rightarrow\;(\beta^2-\alpha^2)^{2}~=~ 4\sin^{2}(v_--v_+)\,v_+^{2}\, v_-^{2}$. The condition for the diagonal is $v_+\, v_- \,\cos(v_--v_+)~=~ \alpha\,\beta\,\cos(\alpha-\beta)\;\rightarrow\; 4\cos^{2}(v_--v_+)\,v_+^{2}\, v_-^{2} ~=~ 4\alpha^{2}\beta^{2}cos^{2}(\alpha-\beta)$. Therefore, $4v_+^{2}\, v_-^{2}=(\beta^2-\alpha^2)+4\alpha^{2}\beta^{2}cos^{2}(\alpha-\beta)$ (Corrected*)

Comment: You are right, I have to watch my 2's ...